# Can't remove volume group

Tags: linux, hard-drive, lvm

I have a missed device in vgroup lvm. I want remove lvm group.

I did

```
# vgremove lvm --force

WARNING: Device for PV 6bVVia-tsco-GEyq-1zHZ-Vn8W-Eg0v-MNZMmG not found or rejected by a filter.
Aborting vg_write: No metadata areas to write to!
```

---

```
# vgdisplay 
  WARNING: Device for PV 6bVVia-tsco-GEyq-1zHZ-Vn8W-Eg0v-MNZMmG not found or rejected by a filter.
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               lvm
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        0
  Metadata Sequence No  4966
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                32
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                0
  VG Size               <3,00 TiB
  PE Size               32,00 MiB
  Total PE              98303
  Alloc PE / Size       47232 / 1,44 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       51071 / <1,56 TiB
  VG UUID               X45X4f-3Po2-XRHb-sbiH-2cn0-pP6m-SZ8LhP

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               lvm1
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3167
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                23
  Open LV               14
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <2,00 TiB
  PE Size               32,00 MiB
  Total PE              65535
  Alloc PE / Size       19264 / 602,00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       46271 / 1,41 TiB
  VG UUID               OswxV5-YEMj-wiM7-fwAW-A61O-MpfQ-nXb3Vr
```

`# pvs
  WARNING: Device for PV 6bVVia-tsco-GEyq-1zHZ-Vn8W-Eg0v-MNZMmG not found or rejected by a filter.
  WARNING: Device for PV 6bVVia-tsco-GEyq-1zHZ-Vn8W-Eg0v-MNZMmG not found or rejected by a filter.
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree 
  /dev/zd16  lvm1 lvm2 a--  <2,00t  1,41t
  [unknown]  lvm  lvm2 u-m  <3,00t <1,56t`

Any idea to remove vg?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use `--removemissing` or force delete VG if metadata area equal zero as in my case.

Make block device from file and include in `$VG`:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/tmp.raw bs=1M count=100
losetup -f
losetup /dev/loop0 /tmp/tmp.raw
vgextend $VG /dev/loop0
```

After that I have `Metadata Areas        1`

```
vgremove --force $VG
```

and remove pvdevice:

```
pvremove /dev/loop0
```

Comment: `vgremove` takes the `--force` or `-f` flag before the VG name

Answer (score 4):

Run `vgreduce --removemissing $VG` first. This will remove all "partial" LVs - that's any LVs using the missing disk. Man: [vgreduce(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/vgreduce).